# What does it mean that The Throne of Allah being on the water?

Tags: tafseer

It is mentioned in various parts of the Quran for example the verse [11:7] says "He it is Who created the heavens and the earth in six Days - and His Throne was over the Waters -  that He might try you, which of you is best in conduct."

Comment: Please add citation/references, to save this question from being closed/downvoted !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allah's Throne was on Water - Clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/allahs-throne-was-on-water-clarification)

Answer (score 1):

Majma' al-Bayan, by Shaykh Tabarsi:

> It is clear from this verse that Arsh and water existed before the creation of heavens and the earth. [ref](http://www.porsemanequran.com/content/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%B4-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D8%A8)

Nahj al-Balagha, Sermon 1:

> Praise is due to Allah whose worth cannot be described: Then Almighty created forth wind and made its movement sterile, perpetuated its position, intensified its motion and spread it far and wide. Then He ordered the wind to raise up deep waters and to intensify the waves of the oceans. So the wind churned it like the churning of curd and pushed it fiercely into the firmament throwing its front position on the rear and the stationary on the flowing till its level was raised and the surface was full of foam.
>
> Then Almighty raised the foam on to the open wind and vast firmament and made there-from the seven skies and made the lower one as a stationary surge and the upper one as protective ceiling and a high edifice without any pole to support it or nail to hold it together.
>
> Then He decorated them with stars and the light of meteors and hung in it the shining sun and effulgent moon under the revolving sky, moving ceiling and rotating firmament. [ref](https://www.al-islam.org/nahjul-balagha-part-1-sermons/sermon-1-praise-due-allah-whose-worth-cannot-be-described#creation-angels)

[similar question here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/allahs-throne-was-on-water-clarification]

Comment: Please use the formatting tools when answering/questioning, when you cite/quote anything/anyone please quote them/it using **>** before the citation/reference.